# Mysql - Filtering out rows without inner joins

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

(I don't know how to title this question)
I have a table say t1 with 3 fields.

```
 f1----f2----f3
 1     v1     0
 2     v2     0
 3     v3     0
 4     v2    10
 5     v3    10
```

I want to pick up values from the tables if `f3 = 0 or f3 = 10`. However, if there is record with `f3 = 10`, then it would override `0`.
To make it easier to understand,

```
Q1: select * from t1 where f3 = 0  => returns (1,v1,0), (2,v2,0), (3,v3, 0)
Q2: select * from t1 where f3 = 10 => returns           (2,v2,10),(3,v3,10)
```

What I want is `(1,v1,0), (2,v2,10), (3,v3,10)`. I want to do this with some simple if statement in the where condition.
Is this possible?

Comment: if you  `select ... f3=10`, then it'd be impossible to return any `f3=0` rows...

Comment: you want to filter down to the rows with `f3 = 0 or 10`, and then return the row for each `v2` with the highest `f3`, right?

Comment: do you need the pk for a specific reason or can you do without?

Comment: If that's what you want, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: @Marc B: Ofcourse, specifying f3=0 wouldn't fetch any 10s. What I wish to do, is to combine the two queries and make a where condition with some IF statements and achieve the expected result.

Comment: Yes, I need the pk...

Comment: What if there's no corresponding f3 = 0 record for a f3 = 10 record?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
 Select f1, f2, MAX(f3) from t1
 where f3 IN (0, 10)
 group by f2;
```

Comment: Using `MAX()` on f3 only, you won't have the correct values for the f1 column.

Comment: the results woudl require a MIN(f1) but that really makes zero sense since it is a key